# Laravel : .eav file not created in root

Tags: laravel

After using below command .env file no created in root

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project
```

and getting error while accessing url

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

Is there any wrong with this command or any other setting ?
any idea please share

Comment: what's the error ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your `.env` file using the `.env.example` file to configure the database and everything else as needed. Be sure to generate a key with the artisan command `key:generate` as well. By default, laravel uses the configuration files inside the config folder.

Comment: Galanx, i can not seen env-example or .env  in root. is there under any specfic directory ?

Comment: No it should be in the root directory of the laravel application. When you created your project, did you get any error while creating it?

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
You made a reference to a non-existent script php artisan package:discover
You made a reference to a non-existent script php artisan key:generate
i getting this message at last after installed all packages

Comment: at starting also showing this one line :
You made a reference to a non-existent script php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"

Comment: Your composer might be out of date, please run "composer self-update" and "composer global update"

Comment: Agree, sounds like a composer issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to resolve, just copy .env and copy content from .env.example

or

run bellow command:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make one in a text editor. There's nothing special about them. Just lookup an example of one and make sure you fill in all the necessary env variables.

```
vim .env
```

or

```
nano .env
```

from your app root and add the following:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

[Here's an online example if you need it.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-laravel-environment-variables)

**EDIT**

If you're worried about the file permissions, `sudo chmod 644 .env` should be fine. Make sure you add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file if it's not already there. You should never track your environment variables in version control.